# Issue with nested async/await not awaiting

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

I've not yet mastered async/awaits and I'm struggling to figure out why my code is not working as intended. I've tried to find similar scenarios online but not had any luck so any help is really appreciated!

I have a parent array of children arrays filled with objects i.e. [[],[],[]]. These objects contain data that I first send to an embedding API to get some additional data, and then add to a database. Both of these are async calls.
The children arrays are essentially acting as batches of the parent array because the embedding API can only handle a certain quantity of API calls at a time.

I loop through the parent array and for each child array I call the embedAndSave() which calls the embedding api and then stores in the db

```
for (const batch of batches) {
     await embedAndSave(batch, client)
}
console.log("Hello World")
```

```
const embedAndSave = async (batchArray, client, indexName='articles') => {
    
// STEP 1 - Embed the objects via the API service

    const embeddedArticles = await Promise.all(
        batchArray.map(async (element) => { 
            console.log('log 1')
            const sbertVector = element['articleText'] ? await getEmbedding(element['articleText']) : undefined
            console.log('log 2')
            return { ...element, sbertVector: sbertVector}
        })
    )
    console.log('log 3', embeddedArticles)
    const articlesReadyForDb = embeddedArticles //filtering out elements for which the api call above failed
        .filter((element) => {
            return element['sbertVector'] !== undefined
    })



    // STEP 2 - Add the updated data to the opensearch DB

    await Promise.all(
        articlesReadyForDB.map(async (element) => {
            if(element !== undefined){
                return await addArticleToDb(client, indexName, element)
            }
        })
    )
```

I am expecting the logs to appear something like the below if we have  objects in each child array and 2 child arrays
`[[{},{}],[{},{}]]`

```
//For Child array 1
log 1
<output of getEmbedding>
log 2
log 1
<output of getEmbedding>
log 2

log 3
<output of addArticleToDb>
<output of addArticleToDb>

// For Child Array 2
log 1
<output of getEmbedding>
log 2
log 1
<output of getEmbedding>
log 2

log 3
<output of addArticleToDb>
<output of addArticleToDb>

// hello world logged after for/of loop
Hello World
```

In actual fact I am getting

```
//For Child array 1
log 1
log 1
<output of getEmbedding>
log 2
<output of getEmbedding>
log 2
log 3
<output of addArticleToDb>
<output of addArticleToDb>

//For Child array 1
log 1
log 1
<output of getEmbedding>
log 2
<output of getEmbedding>
log 2
log 3
<output of addArticleToDb>
<output of addArticleToDb>

//no hello world received
```

Comment: `map` will immediately start all the calls.  It will not wait for the "current" mapped item to finish before iterating.  Use a regular for loop to actually actually `await` the current iteration.

Comment: I'm basing those duplicates on the fact that you expect the logs to be `1 2 1 2 3` instead of `1 1 2 2 3`.  If I'm incorrect in that assumption, let me know.

Comment: thanks! I didn't realise that `map` behaved like that - will change my code, and hopefully get it working as expected